# F# Array with tuples or Map

Tags: f#

I have a sample code and some question.

Simple type property

```
member val CabinetNetworkState : uint8 = 0uy with get, set
member this.CabinetNetworkStateAsValues : (CabinetNetworkStateHosts * uint8) array =
        let cabinetNetworkStateMap = new ResizeArray<(CabinetNetworkStateHosts * uint8)> ()

        let extNetworkState = (this.CabinetNetworkState >>> 0) &&& uint8 2
        match Enum.IsDefined(typeof<CabinetNetworkState>, extNetworkState) with
        | true ->  cabinetNetworkStateMap.Add (CabinetNetworkStateHosts.EXT, extNetworkState)
        | false -> cabinetNetworkStateMap.Add (CabinetNetworkStateHosts.EXT, 0uy)

        let canNetworkState = (this.CabinetNetworkState >>> 3) &&& uint8 2
        match Enum.IsDefined(typeof<CabinetNetworkState>, canNetworkState) with
        | true ->  cabinetNetworkStateMap.Add (CabinetNetworkStateHosts.CAN, canNetworkState)
        | false -> cabinetNetworkStateMap.Add (CabinetNetworkStateHosts.CAN, 0uy)

        let net1NetworkState = (this.CabinetNetworkState >>> 5) &&& uint8 2
        match Enum.IsDefined(typeof<CabinetNetworkState>, net1NetworkState) with
        | true ->  cabinetNetworkStateMap.Add (CabinetNetworkStateHosts.NET1, net1NetworkState)
        | false -> cabinetNetworkStateMap.Add (CabinetNetworkStateHosts.NET1, 0uy)

        let net2NetworkState = (this.CabinetNetworkState >>> 7) &&& uint8 2
        match Enum.IsDefined(typeof<CabinetNetworkState>, net2NetworkState) with
        | true ->  cabinetNetworkStateMap.Add (CabinetNetworkStateHosts.CAN, net2NetworkState)
        | false -> cabinetNetworkStateMap.Add (CabinetNetworkStateHosts.CAN, 0uy)

        cabinetNetworkStateMap.ToArray()
```

What it does it converts a value into array of bit value and enum that value represents
My question is should I use Map instead of tuple array, or it does not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Map would have a roughly constant time lookup on keys but if there only going to be 4 entries then checking each item in an array will probably be quicker anyway.

I think a much bigger issue is the repetition in the code and use of a `ResizeArray` to write in an imperative style when that can be easily avoided. Both of those issues are covered in this refactor (note that the names I used are quite arbitrary and you can probably come up with better ones):

```
member this.CabinetNetworkStateAsValues : (CabinetNetworkStateHosts * uint8) array =
    let makeStatePair state stateType =
        let networkState = (this.CabinetNetworkState >>> state) &&& 2uy
        if Enum.IsDefined(typeof<CabinetNetworkState>, networkState)
        then stateType, networkState
        else stateType, 0uy
    [|
        makeStatePair 0 CabinetNetworkStateHosts.EXT 
        makeStatePair 3 CabinetNetworkStateHosts.CAN
        makeStatePair 5 CabinetNetworkStateHosts.NET1
        makeStatePair 7 CabinetNetworkStateHosts.CAN
    |]
```